# How to divide variables in java for a GPA calculator

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a GPA calculator for a class of mine. I keep getting an error that has to do with the division I'm trying to do on the GPA calculation and am having trouble with the syntax for sub-strings and how to use them correctly. Below is the code I have so far. If you see anything I can fix that's not to complicated I'm open to all suggestions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GPA
{
    public static void main(String[] mydata)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
        String choice = "";
        String cnum;
        String grade;
        double points;
        double gpa = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String credit= "", totalCredit = "";

        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) 
        {
            cnum = (mydata[0]);
            grade = (mydata[1]);

            if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {points = 4.0;} 
            else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {points = 3.0;} 
            else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {points = 2.0;}         
            else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {points = 1.0;}
            else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {points = 0.0;}

            credit = cnum.substring(3,4);

            //System.out.println("credits = " + totalCredit);

            System.out.println("GPA = " points/Double.parseDouble(credit));
            System.out.print("Enter next course number and grade or ‘Q’ to quit: ");
            System.out.println();
            choice = sc.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not bad but there are a couple syntactical errors with your code:

1. The `println` argument needs to be concatenated with a `+`:

   ```
   System.out.println("GPA = " + points / Double.parseDouble(credit));
   ```
2. The local variable, `points`, needs to be initialized since your `if-else` conditions are not exhaustive (ie: `grade` has a runtime range of A, B, C, D, or F but `grade` can technically be assigned to whatever is in `mydata[1]`). Either add an `else` condition or assign an initial value to `points`:

   ```
   double points = 0.0;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response, its kind of working now except for I dont know how to iterate the program so I can add more grades and calculate the GPA based of off 4 or more grades.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include + to concat the strings together :)

```
System.out.println("GPA = " + (points/Double.parseDouble(credit)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, its kind of working now except for I dont know how to iterate the program so I can add more grades and calculate the GPA based of off 4 or more grades.

Comment: Try assigning `choice` to `grade` after the first iteration (with a statement like `if (choice == "") {grade = (mydata[1]);} else {grade = choice;}`).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to be concatenating here.

```
System.out.println("GPA = " + (points/Double.parseDouble(credit)));
```

Instead of

```
System.out.println("GPA = " (points/Double.parseDouble(credit)));
```

And if you want

```
int theGpa = points/Double.parseDouble(credit));
System.out.println("GPA: " + theGpa);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, its kind of working now except for I dont know how to iterate the program so I can add more grades and calculate the GPA based of off 4 or more grades.

Comment: Ok.  Please do note that that was not your initial question.

Comment: @jakeblankenship. Just a friendly reminder that if this answer answered your question, you can accept it by pressing the checkmark next to the answer.